# How to write string and ndarray into a file sequentially?

Tags: python, numpy, io, output

I have 3 numpy ndarrays (say, A,B,C with dimension 2) whose elements' type is floating point. I want to write them sequentially into a file in the following format:

```
“first:”
A

"second:"
B

"third:"
C
```

I have tried the following code and got "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

```
with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
    np.savetxt(f,"A:")
    np.savetxt(f, A, fmt="%s")
    np.savetxt(f,"B:")
    np.savetxt(f, B, fmt='%s')
    np.savetxt(f,"C:")
    np.savetxt(f, C, fmt='%s')
```

Then I tried

```
with open("out.txt", "wb") as f:
   f.write("A:\n")
   np.savetxt(f, A, fmt="%s")
   f.write("B:\n")
   np.savetxt(f, B, fmt='%s')
   f.write("C:\n")
   np.savetxt(f, C, fmt='%s')
```

and got "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, do not just write 'does not work'.  Show us what is wrong and what you expect.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for advice. I updated my description.

Comment: You would need to writ bytes `f.write(b"A:\n")`  because you have opened the file using b for binary mode

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks! this worked for me :-)